# Thread pool pattern in TBB and other libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

Is there any [thread pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) realization in [TBB library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Threading_Building_Blocks)?

If no, where can I find it? Most of open source realizations, that I already found looks unfinished and unstable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what task your application is solving? TBB does not expose its thread pool API, but it has algorithms, task_group, task enque, pipeline and even a non-linear pipeline (from what I hear), so maybe you don't really need a thread pool afterall, maybe there's a way to map your application algorithm onto the APIs that TBB exposes?

Answer (score 2):

TBB doesn't contain any sort of thread pool class you can get at yourself (but see below).  If I ever really needed to create a thread pool myself (and I'd hope I wouldn't, because I'd rather be dealing with the higher level concepts TBB or OpenMP expose), then I'd probably go with this cute [way of using `boost::asio` to provide thread pool functionality](http://think-async.com/Asio/Recipes).

More on TBB specifically: if TBB includes a thread pool then it's an internal implementation detail, and you have some limited control over it through optionally specifying a specific number of threads (and their stack size) when you call `task_scheduler_init`.  But it's entirely possible to not call that and have TBB use its defaults.

In fact note that the docs state:

> An optional parameter to the constructor and method initialize allow you to specify
>   the number of threads to be used for task execution. This parameter is useful for
>   scaling studies during development, but should not be set for production use.
>   The reason for not specifying the number of threads in production code is that in a
>   large software project, there is no way for various components to know how many
>   threads would be optimal for other threads. Hardware threads are a shared global
>   resource. It is best to leave the decision of how many threads to use to the task
>   scheduler.

But if you're worrying about thread pools, or used what support TBB has for explicit thread objects to implement one, you'd be missing out on most of the value in TBB.  To exploit that, you really need to be thinking in terms of tasks and task parallelism, not threads.

Comment: I note recent TBB now includes a task_arena class which kind of lets you carve off bits of TBB's implicit thread pool into separate... well they're not really pools, hence the arena name.  But they do let you limit a job to a certain number of worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no

Long answer:

TBB thread class is just a wrapper for the underlying OS threads that approximates the C++11 thread. But it's useful for code portability.

I agree with the general suggestions that you might be better to rely on the highly optimized task scheduling that TBB offers instead.

Or consider the newly added flow_graph structures.

If you want to explore threads yourself then rolling your own threadgroup class that starts stops and joins all its contained threads is relatively straightforward no?